# Prefill FBGRAPH API comment textbox

Tags: iphone, fb-graph

Please find attached snap.
http://s17.postimage.org/4jwwze80v/FBTest_Demo.png

I want the `@"Description"` field in desired `comment text box` as shown in image.I'm using `@"message"` field for that. But it does nothing. 
I've come to conclusion that message field is closed `since July 12, 2011` . Is this could be the reason for my problem if this is true? And also lemme know if anybody has suggestion over this.

I'm passing params as following
..     [fb dialog:@"stream.publish" andParams:params andDelegate:self];

where params contains my fbappid & message field

Answer (score -1):

textFieldPassword.placeholder = @"Enter Comment here";Please try this.

Comment: that textbox is not named as textFieldPassword. And I'm not able to find any placeholder in entire FBGraphAPI. So not able to apply this.

Comment: Is the box  UITextField or not?

Comment: It is pre-built box comes with GraphAPI. So how to identify it?

Comment: I know. But fb does not allow to access its textbox.